# Error from trying to build archive Xcode: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently updated my Xcode and reinstalled an older version for an app that is built on an older version of Xcode.

So I now have Xcode 10 as well as Xcode 9.2 installed on my computer.

I have set the default in the command line to Xcode 9.2, I have changed the location to Xcode 9.2

I have tried to load Name.xcworkspace as opposed to Name.xcodeproj in finder.

I have tried deintegrating and reinstalling my Cocoapods

And yet I keep getting this error whenever I try to build an archive.

What else can I try? I need to push a new build to the App Store, and with this bug, I can't at all.

I am also noticing that Jump to Definition does not work either, so I am assuming there must be some relationship here.

That being said, development versions of the app build fine for the simulator.

What else could be going wrong here? How do I fix this?

I've seen some questions about this, but I have done everything those other questions ask

Full error log:

```
Ld /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Candy.build/Release-iphoneos/Candy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Candy normal armv7
    cd /Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 9.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode\ 9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -L/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/CardIO/CardIO -L/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -L/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ARChromeActivity -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AeroGearHttp -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AeroGearOAuth2 -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Bolts -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/EAIntroView -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/EARestrictedScrollView -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/EmitterKit -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Eureka -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKLoginKit -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FacebookCore -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FacebookLogin -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FacebookShare -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GMStepper -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/KINWebBrowser -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Koloda -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PKHUD -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SimpleKeychain -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SnapKit -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SwiftyJSON -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/TUSafariActivity -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Unbox -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/UnboxedAlamofire -F/Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/pop -F/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/AppsFlyerFramework -F/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/Button -F/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/Google/Frameworks -F/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada-final/candy/Candy/Pods/Pushwoosh/Framework -filelist /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Candy.build/Release-iphoneos/Candy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Candy.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Candy.build/Release-iphoneos/Candy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Candy_lto.o -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/Candy.app/Candy -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode\ 9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Candy.build/Release-iphoneos/Candy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Candy.swiftmodule -ObjC -lCardIO -lGoogleAnalytics -lPayPalMobile -lc++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework ARChromeActivity -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework AeroGearHttp -framework AeroGearOAuth2 -framework Alamofire -framework AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator -framework AppsFlyerLib -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -framework Bolts -framework Button -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework EAIntroView -framework EARestrictedScrollView -framework EmitterKit -framework Eureka -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework FacebookCore -framework FacebookLogin -framework FacebookShare -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GGLAnalytics -framework GGLCore -framework GMStepper -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework KINWebBrowser -framework Koloda -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework PKHUD -framework Pushwoosh -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SimpleKeychain -framework SnapKit -framework StoreKit -framework SwiftyJSON -framework SystemConfiguration -framework TUSafariActivity -framework UIKit -framework Unbox -framework UnboxedAlamofire -framework iAd -framework pop -framework AdSupport -framework iAd -framework Pods_Candy -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Candy.build/Release-iphoneos/Candy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Candy_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Candy-dcszzxlovxhznvggxxjbcwvojdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Candy/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Candy.build/Release-iphoneos/Candy.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Candy

ld: warning: Some object files have incompatible Objective-C category definitions. Some category metadata may be lost. All files containing Objective-C categories should be built using the same compiler.
ld: could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1000.11.45.2_0' Reader: '900.0.39.2_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 9.0.0, (clang-900.0.39.2)' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Show more details of the error from the issue navigator.

Comment: Added the error log

Comment: Does your code include Objective-C or just the Cocoapods? What version is of Xcode was the app built under when you say older version? Did you run the covert to update code?

Comment: It was built under 9.2 or 9.3. I updated Xcode, but I reinstalled older Xcode. I am getting these errors in Xcode 9.2. And no, the app is entirely written in Swift. Some pods are using objective-C.

Comment: So I was able to get this to work by disabling bitcode, but that seems like an ineffective fix

Answer (score 0):

Go to xCode > Prefrences > Locations, and delete all Archives and Derived Data, do a clean build and you are done.

Comment: I tried that too. Did not work. Only switching bitcode to off worked

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander explained in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your project, Xcode invokes clang for Objective-C targets and swift/swiftc for Swift targets. Both of these compilers compile the app to an intermediate representation (IR), one of these IRs is bitcode. From this IR, a program called LLVM takes over and creates the binaries needed for x86 32 and 64 bit modes (for the simulator) and arm6/arm7/arm7s/arm64 (for the device). Normally, all of these different binaries are lumped together in a single file called a fat binary.

The ENABLE_BITCODE option cuts out this final step. It creates a version of the app with an IR bitcode binary. This has a number of nice features, but one giant drawback: it can't run anywhere. In order to get an app with a bitcode binary to run, the bitcode needs to be recompiled (maybe assembled or transcoded… I'm not sure of the correct verb) into an x86 or ARM binary.

Now, in your case some third party library must have bitcode disabled and hence you will also need you disable bitcode in your project. @Andrew